# Move docker desktop data folder (windows containers)

Tags: docker, docker-desktop, windows-container

I'm using docker desktop (4.X) over win10 pro. We are building Windows applications and using **Windows containers**.

On our setup, the folder C:\ProgramData\Docker(images/windowsfilter/tmp & co) can grow up to hundreds of GB, and i need to move this folder to an alternative location.

Again, i am using **WINDOWS CONTAINERS** (i do not care about wsl2 or hyper-v specific solutions)

- I tried moving / creating a junction between
  C:\ProgramData\ Docker => D:\DockerData, but windows containers backend does not start.
- If i switch back to linux containers, everything is working fine (and i know how to move WSL2 vhdx, if needed, but again, i DO NOT NEED THAT information).
- Moving HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileList\ProgramData location BEFORE installing docker desktop, works, but it is not an acceptable solution
- I tried configuring data-root directory in %USERPROFILE%.docker\windows-daemon.json, But it does not work, windows containers backend does not start.

Please give me a reliable way to move the C:\ProgramData\Docker folder to another location.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, when utilizing Windows Containers, it is not yet feasible to relocate the C:ProgramDataDocker folder to another location. This is so that container images and other data can be stored in this directory, which the Docker for Windows service is hard-coded to utilize.

You might try using a symbolic link to reroute the C:ProgramDataDocker folder to an other place as a solution. This may not be a reliable approach, though, as the Docker for Windows service might not handle the symbolic link correctly, which would prevent the service from starting.

Comment: Can you source me that information ? (docker for windows is open-source)

Comment: After doing a deeper research I found it is possible, here it is the referece:
[link](https://www.ntweekly.com/2019/09/20/how-to-change-docker-storage-data-folder-on-windows-server-2016/)

Comment: You have to add
"data-root": "<PathToNewDirectory>"
to the Docker Engine configuration in the Docker Desktop GUI Settings if you are using Docker for Desktop since Docker for Desktop will otherwise overwrite your configuration file with the previous settings again.